# making a wordpress intranet site on google cloud

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, intranet

Some preface: I'm not great at writing code. I am working on a wordpress site. I recently migrated it to google cloud. I want the site to be accessible only from my company. The company is pretty big (20,000+ employees) and uses G-suite and my google cloud is linked with the company email. Is there a firewall setting or something to make my wordpress site intranet. I don't have admin rights.
I don't want to use the Google Apps Wordpress Login.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Intranet site using [VPC networking and Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls) which can assist you in creating your network and setting [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) for it.

In order to ensure only your company network will connect to it and set a secure connection to your intranet you can set up a [VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpns) or [Peering network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).

You still need to be concerned about backdoor connections to your Intranet VM instances via their external IP addresses. You can follow this [documentation guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely) which provides more information about ‘Protecting services on machines with external IP addresses’.

Using VM instances that do not have an external IP address and using a VPN as described above can give your intranet the level of protection that you need. More information on this can be found in the following [documentation guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances).